# отдать определенный шаблон для определенного урла

Tags: nginx

Прочитал `Руководство для начинающих` и `Как nginx обрабатывает запросы` с  http://nginx.org/ + немного погуглил и пытаюсь для определенного урла отдать определенный шаблон. По неведомым мне причинам при обращении к / шаблон index.html благополучно отдается, а при обращении к /list/ nginx отдает 404 ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Код существующего конфига ниже, вместо %domainname% в конфиге на сервере реальный домен.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name %domainname%;
    root /var/www/%domainname%;

    location / {
            index templates/index.html;
    }

    location /list/ {
            index templates/list.html;
    }

}
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что `templates/list.html` ищется внутри папки (существует она или нет) `var/www/%domainname%/list`. Попробуйте указать `index /templates/list.html` (внимание на лидирующий слэш).

Comment: @Etki, да, лидирующий слэш решил проблему. спасибо

Comment: Etki: прилагательное *leading* [переводится на русский как «ведущий»](http://wooordhunt.ru/word/leading).

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

Подозреваю, что `templates/list.html` ищется внутри папки (существует она или нет) `/var/www/%domainname%/list`. Попробуйте указать `index /templates/list.html` (внимание на лидирующий слэш).